# New vector asset in drawable folder can't be called from xml

Tags: android, xml, android-vectordrawable, xml-drawable

So, basically I'm creating a new Vector Asset using a particular material icon (in this case navigation menu icon).

And after that, I want to try that new icon in my `FloatingActionButton`, but, silly enough, the asset I just created doesn't detected by Android Studio, and returned an error like the screenshot below.

[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp" />
```

I also tried to add `.xml` to the end of the code and copying the file reference and pasted it in the code, but both doesn't work.

---

Then I decided to look at the error details, which is:

[image]

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Color value '@android:drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp' must start with #
```

---

And then I think, "oh! maybe I forgot the #". So, I opened the xml file, only to find that I already wrote the #.

[image]

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" 
          android:pathData="M3,18h18v-2L3,16v2zM3,13h18v-2L3,11v2zM3,6v2h18L21,6L3,6z"/>
</vector>
```

---

**So, is there anyone find what did I do wrong? I'm new to AS, and Android Dev, so I might missed something silly though.**

P.S. I also tried to reopen Android Studio, and rebuild my project, but it's no good.

P.S.S. I'm using Android Studio 2.1

Comment: Please post actual samples not images, it's better for everyone, especially people answering who may want to copy your sample and edit the relevant parts

Comment: remove the @android:

Comment: @NickCardoso got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually `@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp`

Or If you are supporting the native Vector version you can use.

```
app:srcCompat:@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp
```

Comment: wow i feel really retarded. Why not the error message say "@ is expected" on the line i wonder? Anyway, it worked, thank you.

Comment: What's the difference? Is it because it's native, so the space required become smaller?

Comment: The native version does not render a bitmap and you can save a lot of space and it has a good quality when resize since it is a Vector image. Although the set-up is bit tricky so you need to pay attention to the setup.

Comment: If you are familiar with anti-aliasing thats the technique used by bitmap to smoothen the image in case of Vectors it is irrelevant and does provide better render results than Rasterize image.

Answer (score 0):

you have included the android namespace in your markup.  As the drawable you are trying to use is not part of the Android framework (it is YOUR drawable folder), this part is not required.

e.g just use: @drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp.xml